# Array Declaration From variable Shell

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I have a variable which is having 4k+ records in the below format

```
echo $value 
"C:211:5814" "C:26:589" "C:211:600" "C:218:600" "C:27:4461"
```

Now when I am trying to assign this to array I keep getting error

```
declare -a arr=(`echo $value`) # even tried arr=(`$value`)
## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
 do
  echo "$i"
  # or do whatever with individual element of the array
 done
```

Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Is there anyway to declare the araay without copying the value in () .
Also, is there any way to print them in batches of 100 rather than 1 at a time.

Regards,

Comment: to use arrays, you need `bash` (or similar).  On Debian or Ubuntu-like systems, bash is the default shell for interactive work but dash is the default shell for scripting.  The error message is consistent with your using dash not bash.

Comment: I am using Bash  #!/bin/bash   root@vm-001:~/output/elastic# ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4189 pts/0    00:00:00 bash

Comment: Don't put information like that in a comment: as you can likely see now, it removes all newlines.  Put it in your question.  Also, the shebang line doesn't guarantee that bash is running the script.  It depends on how you execute the script.  Try `bash scriptname`.

Comment: I am executing it using bash shell

Comment: Please try running `bash scriptname` and then quote __in full__ all output from the command in your question.

Comment: Better yet, run `bash -x scriptname` and quote the complete output in your question.